# How to send an email html template using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that sends email alerts to the users, i made a folder and contains all the files and styles like a normal html.

[image]

In the properties of Email.html, i selected always copy.

To read that file in my method, i used this:

```
var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "EmailTemplate\\Email.html";
string body = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

And to replace the text dinamically, just used `body.Replace("#Text#", newString)`

To send the email i used: `MailMessage`

And the final result is:

[image]

Nothing of the css imported is used, how to load all files?

Note: I edited the image with black lines

Comment: When you send the email, the person receiving it can't read the CSS off your disk. Try hosting it on a CDN or inlining the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Most email clients don't support external stylesheets](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/). You'll need to inline the CSS to get it to show up.

If you don't want to hand-convert things, MailChimp has an [inline CSS converter that I've used in the past](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/). There are other utilities/tools out there too.